# How can I use sort() function in C++ doing something together?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have two arrays as

```
(i) arrStart[]={0 1 3 5 6 8 10 12 15};
(ii) arrEnd[]={4 2 7 11 16 9 14 13 17};
```

I want to sort `arrEnd[]` such that corresponding integer in `arrStart[]` also get swapped matching with integer of `arrEnd[]` like

**Output:**

```
(i) arrStart[]={1 0 3 8 5 12 10 6 15};
(ii) arrEnd[]={2 4 7 9 11 13 14 16 17};
```

I am using

```
sort(arrEnd,arrEnd+8);
```

Is there any logic to get above output such that i could  get rid of writing
complete sorting algorithm?

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the sorting algorithm: just associate the arrStart data with arrEnd data.  For example, **arrEnd[x] = arrEnd[x] * 100 + arrStart[x]**

Comment: Thanks @cup Your solution worked.It required some data manipulation but anyhow worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: Create an array of indices 0 to n-1; Use sort with a lambda compare to compare arrEnd[] elements. Then use the sorted indices to reorder both arrays according to the array of sorted indices.

Method 2: Create an array of pointers to arrEnd[] elements, then sort the array of pointers using a compare function. The compare function only needs to know the type of the elements. Then reorder both arrays according to the array of sorted pointers.

Example for method 2. Reorder in place time complexity is linear, O(n).

```
bool compare(const int *p0, const int *p1)
{
    return *p0 < *p1;
}

int main()
{
int a[8] = {7,5,0,6,4,2,3,1};
char b[8] = {'h','f','a','g','e','c','d','b'};
int *pa[8];
size_t i, j, k;
int ta;
char tb;
    // create array of pointers to a[]
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        pa[i] = &a[i];
    // sort array of pointers to a[]
    std::sort(pa, pa+sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), compare);
    // reorder a[] and b[] according to the array of pointers to a[]
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++){
        if(i != pa[i]-a){
            ta = a[i];
            tb = b[i];
            k = i;
            while(i != (j = pa[k]-a)){
                a[k] = a[j];
                b[k] = b[j];
                pa[k] = &a[k];
                k = j;
            }
            a[k] = ta;
            b[k] = tb;
            pa[k] = &a[k];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]); i++)
        std::cout << b[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```